# Time Complexity-Recursively Remove All Adjacent Duplicates

Tags: java, string, time-complexity

I was having difficulty finding the time complexity of this code. I think it's O(n), but in some places, it's given O(n^2). Can anyone help me?

```
class Solution{  
    String solve(String s){  
        StringBuilder ans=new StringBuilder();  
        int i=0;  
        while(i<s.length()){  
           if(i<s.length()-1 && s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(i+1)){  
               while(i<s.length()-1 && s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(i+1)){  
                   i++;  
               }  
           }  
           else{  
               ans.append(s.charAt(i));  
           }  
           i++;  
          
            
           
        }
        return ans.toString();
       
    }
    String rremove(String s) {
       String s1="";
       while(s1.length()!=s.length()){
           s1=s;
           s=solve(s);
       }
       return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be O(n) only. Because at most solve(s) is called only 1 time, and in that 1 time it'll remove all adjacent duplicates.

Maybe people thought that solve(s) is removing adjacent duplicates 1 at time and that solve(s) is being called n times and hence they thought O(n^2) but that's not true according to me.

Comment: Hey Kalyan! I feel the solve(s) is not being called just one time. It's not recursion. Take the example- edcbaabcde. @Kalyan

Comment: Yup, you're right. It's O(n^2). But you can do it in O(n) using a stack.